# Perl 2D Array with undef to CSV

Tags: arrays, perl, csv

I have to change a 2D array with undef enteries into a csv file. The dumper values looks like

```
VAR1      [
            'Entry1',
            undef,
            undef,
            undef,
            17
          ],
          [
            'Entry2',
            8,
            undef,
            undef,
            17
          ],
          [
            'Entry3',
            undef,
            4,
            undef,
            17
          ],
```

For undef, I need to put 0. I am using the code below, but its not giving required results.

```
    open MYFILE, ">>new.csv";
    for ($i=1,$i <= $flag, $i++){
        print MYFILE "$outputArray[$i][0],";
        for ($j=0,$j<= 4, $j++){
        print MYFILE int($outputArray[$i][$j]).",";
        }
        print MYFILE "\n";
    }
    close MYFILE;
```

My final csv would be something like

```
Entry1,0,0,0,17
Entry2,8,0,0,17
Entry3,0,4,0,17
```

Comment: `for ($i=1,$i <= $flag, $i++)` means something very different from `for ($i=1;$i <= $flag; $i++)`, which is probably what you want.

Comment: If you are using the code i wrote for you to make the array, replace `$val = ''` with `$val = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `foreach` style of `for` when iterating over a multidimensional array.  There's no reason to keep track of indexes if you don't have to.

Additionally, you can use the defined or operator `//` with `map` to quickly translate all your `undef` values to your preferred default.

```
for my $row (@outputArray) {
    print MYFILE join(',', map {$_ // 0} @$row), "\n";
}
```